# A ball with respect to a discrete metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a ball of radius $1$, then:

$$B_{\mathbb{R}^2,d_{disc}}((0,0),1) = \{(0,0)\}$$

But if we increase the radius to be larger than $1$, how is it that the ball would encompass all of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Because, in the (strictly, "a", but we always pick this one) discrete metric, the distance $d(x,y)$ when $x\neq y$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discrete metric on $\mathbb{R^2},$ $d:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$  is defined as follows:$$\begin{equation}
    d(x,y)=
    \begin{cases}
      0, & \text{ if}\ x=y \\
      1, & \text{ if } x\ne y
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}$$whrere $x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb{R^2}$.

So $d(x,y)\le 1,\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R^2}$.

$$\therefore B_{\mathbb{R}^2,d}((0,0),r)=\mathbb{R^2},\forall r>1.$$